# JAVA double variable math does not tally, is it bc of binary representation issues?

Tags: java, math, double

Basically this was a homework that I had to do about rectangles. The problem came when I needed to do simple math to calculate the x and y values of the vertices e.g. (x-width/2), and because i needed to use those values in more than one method, i created new variables in the class for that simple math (x1 = (x-width/2), x2, y1, y2 etc), for readability. For some reason, in my methods, using the variables produced wrong results. when I went back and replaced them with the math again, it worked.

My question is why are the variables i made (under //WEIRD VARIABLES) not working inside the contains method?

here is my code:

```
package com.example;

public class MyRectangle2D {
    double x,y;
    double width, height;
    //a couple of getters and setters
    //constructor
    MyRectangle2D(){
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        width=1.0;
        height=1.0;
    }
    MyRectangle2D(double X, double Y, double Width, double Height){
        x=X;
        y=Y;
        width=Width;
        height=Height;
    }

    // WEIRD VARIABLES
    private double x1 = x-(width/2);
    private double x2 = (x+(width/2));
    private double y1 = (y-(height/2));
    private double y2 = (y+(height/2));

    //methods
    boolean contains(double X, double Y){
        /* initially wrote: 
           return (!( X<x1 || X>x2 || Y <y1 || Y>y2 )); 
           didnt work, bc for some reason x1,x2,y1,y2 were all 0.0
           the below works well: */
        return (!(X<(x-(width/2)) || X>(x+(width/2)) || Y <(y-(height/2)) || Y>(y+(height/2))));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRectangle2D b = new MyRectangle2D(1, 2, 3, 4);
        System.out.println(b.x1); // 0.0 (should be -0.5)
        System.out.println(b.x); // 1.0 (correct)
        System.out.println(b. width); // 3.0 (correct)
        System.out.println("(1.0,2.0) in b? (true?) " + b.contains(1.0,2.0)); //true (correct)
    }
}
```

I'm perfectly fine just writing the math out again and again, but in my homework they wanted me to create a method to check if this rectangle contains another rectangle, like

```
    boolean contains(MyRectangle2D r){}
```

which means i need to write r.(x-(width/2)) <= (x-(width/2)) etc. to write my conditions, which seems tedious and messy. It seemed logical to me to create those x1,x2,y1,y2 variables as a form of shortcut, since the math were the same formula and it would be cleaner and I could directly use r.x1 instead of r.(x-(width/2))

**tl;dr:** when i println x1, it gives me 0.0, but when i println x-(width/2), it gives me -0.5, which is correct.

i've been trying to figure out why the math goes wrong but i'm still lost. any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment bellow is being done before any constructor. Doesn't matter that the constructores come first. All the fields declaration are processed first.

```
 // WEIRD VARIABLES
    private double x1 = x-(width/2);
    private double x2 = (x+(width/2));
    private double y1 = (y-(height/2));
    private double y2 = (y+(height/2));
```

Maybe a solution for your problem is to make the assignment inside the contructor, like:

```
//declare the filds outside any method
private double x1;
private double x2;
private double y1;
private double y2;

MyRectangle2D(){
   //... Your normal code here
   buildWeird();
}
MyRectangle2D(double X, double Y, double Width, double Height){
    //... Your normal code here
    buildWeird();
}
private void buildWeird(){
    this.x1 = x-(width/2);
    this.x2 = (x+(width/2));
    this.y1 = (y-(height/2));
    this.y2 = (y+(height/2));
}
```

Comment: that works great! thank you

Comment: You can't access `this` in a static method.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of fields during their declaration (like `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`) are done after the call to `super()` and before any other statement in the constructor. In your case, that happens before the assignment of `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` so `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` will be 0, regardless if you place the field declarations before or after the constructor.

The solution is to move the assignment in the constructor, at the end.